# Will asking for an answer hurt my negotiation position?

Tags: software-industry, salary, negotiation

(I don't think my question is a duplicate of [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/42929/politely-push-job-offer), because I'm not asking how to do it)

I have managed to get a job offer from company A, which I like, but I am still waiting for a reply from company B, which I like more. I think I did quite decently during the interviewing process and am somehow confident that I'll get a positive response. However, I did the last interview 5 days ago and I thought they'd be much faster.

Of course, I can't just assume that I'll get an offer, turn down A's offer and wait. I'm thinking of writing my contact person and asking for an answer.

Would that hurt my negotiation status, if they decide to make me an offer?

PS: I'd very much prefer to avoid things like accepting A's offer and then rejecting it if I get an offer from B.

Comment: Be patient.  He who flinches first usually does not win.

Comment: This is very common.  Simply let Company B know that you have an offer from another company in hand, but you're waiting to make a decision until you hear a response from them.

Comment: related: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/34004/how-can-i-ask-my-employer-to-quickly-make-me-an-offer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Having time be against you is bad for negotiating.
Having another opportunity is good for negotiating.

So those two probably roughly balance out.

Just tell them you have another offer and ask whether it would be possible for them to move up the decision.

You can motivate this by saying you'd prefer to work for them, which also shouldn't hurt your negotiating position, because most employers would much rather want an employee that actually wants to work for them as opposed to one who will just jump ship once they get a better offer.

What are the alternatives? Keeping A waiting? Hoping you get an offer in time, but accepting A's offer if you don't? Declining A's offer and potentially getting neither? Those seem like significantly worse options than potentially hurting your negotiating position a bit (especially if you'd prefer to work for B regardless).

Answer (score 2):

You're in a highly desirable spot.  You aren't asking for an answer, you're telling them they're about to lose you.  If they like you, they will get back to you quickly, and you'll be able to demand a higher salary than you would otherwise.

So the answer is no, this won't hurt your negotiation status with Company B, but rather the opposite.

Comment: This: "they're about to lose you". Recruiting is candidate finding a job, but also company finding a good employee